# How to separate 2 POST and 2 GET method in 1 controller class in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

i am developing web app that have a transaction for buying a product and that transaction required a customer data. so in that transaction form, i add a modal form for user to add a new customer data.

here currently it's look like :

[link to open the add new customer modal form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYyIj.png)

[modal form to add customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETejM.png)

And here my full controller class :

```
@Controller
```

public class InvoiceProductController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
private MsEmployeeService msEmployeeService;

@Autowired
private MsCustomerService msCustomerService;

@Autowired
CustomerFormValidator customerFormValidator;

@Autowired
private MsLocationService msLocationService;

@Autowired
private MsReligionService msReligionService;

// Set a form validator
@InitBinder("msCustomer")
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(customerFormValidator);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/trproduct", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView trproduct(Locale locale, HttpSession session) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("entryinvoiceproduct");
    MsUser loggedInUser = (MsUser) session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");
    List<MsEmployee> msEmployee = msEmployeeService.findEmployeeByJobsAndLocation("BEAUTY CONSULTANT",
            (short) loggedInUser.getMsLocation().getId());

    List<MsCustomer> msCustomer = msCustomerService.findAll();

    mav.addObject("listCustomer", msCustomer);
    mav.addObject("beautyConsultant", msEmployee);
    mav.addObject("defaultLocation", loggedInUser);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/trproduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customerForm") @Validated MsCustomer msCustomer, BindingResult result,
        Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    logger.debug("saveOrUpdateUser() : {}", msCustomer);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        populateDefaultModel(model);
        return "/trproduct";
    } else {

        // Add message to flash scope
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
        if (msCustomer.isNew()) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "User added successfully!");
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "User updated successfully!");
        }

        msCustomerService.persist(msCustomer);

        // POST/REDIRECT/GET
        return "/trproduct";
        // POST/FORWARD/GET
        // return "user/list";

    }
}

// show add customer form
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddCustomerForm(Model model, HttpSession session) {

    logger.debug("showAddCustomerForm()");

    MsCustomer msCustomer = new MsCustomer();

    MsUser loggedInUser = (MsUser) session.getAttribute("loggedInUser");

    msCustomer.setUpdateUserId(loggedInUser.getId());
    msCustomer.getMsLocation().setId(loggedInUser.getMsLocation().getId());

    model.addAttribute("customerForm", msCustomer);

    populateDefaultModel(model);

    return "";
}

private void populateDefaultModel(Model model) {

    List<MsLocation> msLocation = msLocationService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("locationList", msLocation);

    List<MsReligion> msReligion = msReligionService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("religionList", msReligion);

}
```

}

and here my jsp, that calling the modal form in it :

```css
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<!-- CSS -->

<link href='<c:url value="/resources/datatables/datatables.css" />'
 rel="stylesheet">

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/datatables/datatables.js" />"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#invoicedtls').DataTable({
   "pageLength" : 8,
   "lengthMenu" : [ 8, 16, 32, 64, 100 ],
   select : true
  });

  $('#invoicepayments').DataTable({
   "pageLength" : 8,
   "lengthMenu" : [ 8, 16, 32, 64, 100 ],
   select : true
  });

  $('#existingcustomer').DataTable({
   "pageLength" : 8,
   "lengthMenu" : [ 8, 16, 32, 64, 100 ],
   select : true
  });

  //  $("body").on("click", ".use-address", function() {
  //   var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".custid").text();
  //   var name = $(this).closest("tr").find(".custname").text();
  //   alert(id + " , " + name);
  //  });
 });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <h4>Invoice Header</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <form role="form">
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label>Customer :</label>

    <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase">
     <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
       data-toggle="dropdown">
       Customer <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>

      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
       <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNewCustomer">New</a></li>
       <li><a data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modalExistingCustomer">Existing</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- /btn-group -->
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <label>Beauty Consultant :</label> <select id="disabledSelect"
     class="form-control">
     <option value="-1">Select a Beauty Consultant</option>
     <c:forEach items="${beautyConsultant}" var="bc">
      <option value="${bc.id}">${bc.name}</option>
     </c:forEach>
    </select>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="form-group pull-right">
   <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add New Product</button>
  </div>
  <h4>Product List</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <!--   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">  -->
  <table id="invoicedtls" class="display highlight">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Product</th>
     <th>Price</th>
     <th>Qty</th>
     <th>Discount Value</th>
     <th>Discount Percent</th>
     <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
  </table>

 </div>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <div class="form-group pull-right">
   <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add New Payment</button>
  </div>
  <h4>Payment List</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <!--   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">  -->
  <table id="invoicepayments" class="display highlight">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Pay With</th>
     <th>Bank Name</th>
     <th>Cardholder Name</th>
     <th>Card No</th>
     <th>Card Expired</th>
     <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal Existing Customer -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalExistingCustomer" tabindex="-1"
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalExistingCustomerLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
     aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalExistingCustomerLabel">Select
     Existing Customer</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <!--   <table class="table table-striped table-hover">  -->
    <table id="existingcustomer" class="display compact">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Sex</th>
       <th>Origin</th>
       <th>Religion</th>
       <th>Option</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <c:forEach var="customer" items="${listCustomer}">
       <tr>
        <td class="custid">${customer.id}</td>
        <td class="custname">${customer.firstName}</td>
        <td>${customer.sex}</td>
        <td>${customer.msLocation.name}</td>
        <td>${customer.msReligion.name}</td>
        <td>
         <button class="btn btn-link btn-xs use-address">Use</button>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </c:forEach>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
     data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select
     Customer</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal New Customer -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNewCustomer" tabindex="-1"
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalNewCustomerLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
     aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalNewCustomerLabel">Entry New
     Customer</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="newCustomer" role="form" action="/admin/users/update" method="post">
     <input id="id" name="id" placeholder="Id" value="0" type="hidden"
      value="0" />
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label> <input id="firstName"
       name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"
       type="text" value="" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label> <input id="lastName"
       name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"
       type="text" value="" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label> <input id="email" name="email"
       placeholder="Email" class="form-control" type="text" value="" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label> <input id="password"
       name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"
       type="text" value="" />
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left"
     data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Customer</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 // For demo to fit into DataTables site builder...
 $('#invoicedtls').removeClass('display').addClass(
   'table table-striped table-hover');
 $('#invoicepayments').removeClass('display').addClass(
   'table table-striped table-hover');
 $('#existingcustomer').removeClass('display').addClass(
   'table table-striped table-hover table-compact');
 // Jquery draggable
 $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
  handle : ".modal-header"
 });
</script>
```

What i am confusing is, when using a modal form, in controller class, i cannot separate the @RequestMapping value, because the value will always "/trproduct". In this controller class, i want to save 2 different table (SlInvoiceHdr and MsCustomer), but with the same @RequestMapping value.

I am using the same jsp for the add customer modal.

How can i do it in my controller ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Add  the expected parameter to your request mapping

```
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET , params = { "expectedparam" })
```

1 controller, 2 methods with the same requestMapping, but with different parameters

`@RequestMapping(value = "/trproduct", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView trproduct(Locale locale, HttpSession session) {`

second:

`@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "newform" }) public String showAddCustomerForm(Model model, HttpSession session) {`

But you have to add the the parameter "newform" to your url, like `/trproduct?newform=true`

Comment: so i write just 1 method, but separated with expected parameter ?

Comment: but when using modal dialog form, the url doesn't change.

Comment: i upload my jsp code. so i calling the modal form from the same jsp code that calling from my controller.

Comment: thx, is the GET method or the POST method the problem? You wrote you like to save the customer and the invoice. Where can I find the invoice form?

Comment: on the 2nd image that i post, the invoice form are on the back of the customer form.